# Increase the size of the func overrides popover in xcode

Tags: xcode

How can I increase the the size of the popover in xcode that appears when you override a func?

I have a really large screen, but the popover is tiny and truncates the function names making it difficult to find what you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do that.